# Assigning a keyboard shortcut to a SpinButton in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

I have linked a Spinbutton to a list of cells (with different values in each cell). The Spinbutton works phenomenal, I would just like to be able to have a keyboard shortcut that would automatically change the spinbutton up or down depending on the key board shortcut. If there was a way I could call this code that would work as well.

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 Then Exit Sub
Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0 Then Exit Sub
Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex - 1
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksyoN.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your Spinbutton is located in the sheet with code name Sheet1, then you could include the following in the ThisWorkbook Object code module :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'Set keyboard shortcuts
    Application.OnKey "^%{DOWN}", "Sheet1.SpinButton1_SpinDown"
    Application.OnKey "^%{UP}", "Sheet1.SpinButton1_SpinUp"
    Msgbox "Keyboard shortcuts are now active."

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    'Reset keyboard shortcuts
    Application.OnKey "^%{DOWN}", ""
    Application.OnKey "^%{UP}", ""
    
End Sub
```

> Reminder:
>
> SHIFT = + (plus sign)
>
> CTRL = ^ (caret)
>
> ALT = % (percent sign)
>
> [More details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnKey)

This way, every time you open the workbook the shortcut keys would be assigned and removed when you close the workbook. The shortcut key Ctrl+Alt+UpArrow would call the SpinUp procedure and Ctrl+Alt+DownArrow would call the SpinDown procedure.

Note that the code name of the sheet is different from the sheet name. The code name of a sheet is always on the left in the project explorer window:

[image]

Comment: I added your code right underneath of mine in my VBA and nothing happened. Whenever I push CTRL-ALT-DOWN nothing happens. I renamed my worksheet "Daily Strategies" but in VBA it is labeled Sheet4 'Daily Strategies'.  I am trying to think of anywhere that I have messed up. Thank you

Comment: I don't want this to work just on Workbook_Open, I need it to work throughout the whole entire time that I am in the workbook. When I put your code into ThisWorkbook still nothing happens

Comment: @ANDANDAND – The first time you add the code you have to run it manually by clicking inside the `Workbook_Open` procedure and pressing F5 (or clicking the green play button at the top of the VBE) so the code actually runs. It will be automatic every other time if the code is located in ThisWorkbook.

Comment: I added a picture to my post. The macro won't show up in my VBA to even let me run the code and when I click run (Green play) it won't let me do it either.

Comment: I have clicked in the actual words "Workbook_Open" and I have clicked in the code you have given me while trying to run it. I updated the picture in my post to show that I have clicked in there before running it. I have restarted my file and still isn't working. Would you have any other helpful ways for me to do this? Thank you for your time

Comment: @ANDANDAND – So when you reopen the file and press Ctrl + Alt + Up arrow, does it do nothing or you get an error?

Comment: it does nothing for me

Comment: it displays the Msgbox but won't allow me to use the shortcuts

Comment: @ANDANDAND – Ok, maybe try to change `^%{UP}` to something else I don't know.    This is supposed to work and I don't know what else to tell you.